# No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after upgrade from 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, sound, pulseaudio, 18.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu desktop 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. After that it's not detecting sound devices. I have Lenovo laptop.
[image: Settings/Sound/Output]

[image: Settings/Sound/Input]

I've tried these..
1.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol
sudo alsa force-reload
reboot
```

2.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```

[image: pavucontrol]
3.

```
$ sudo lspci
[sudo] password for surjit: 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Please help

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had a similiar issue that turned out to be a permissions problem with the pulse audio conf file, when I upgraded my Lenovo T440pclaptop to 17.10 last year.
The fix that finally worked for me (sorry, I cant find the original source for reference) was

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
```

hth

Comment: thnx buddy.. now it's working :)

Comment: Yep.  This is a solution for a lot of audio problems.  Example: I had an install of Doom - the recent one crosscompiled not the old one in dosbox.  You had to kill pulse so it could grab openal directly.  Sometimes this resulted in a dangling lock-file for pulse and no audio on reboot.  Probably could just delete the lockfile though.

Comment: Work perfectly with that command in Ubuntu 18.4

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem -- no sound after upgrade to 18.04.1 LTS -- and no audio profiles showed up. This eventually solved the problem:

1. delete .config/pulse/ and .pulse (the latter might not exist)
2. reboot
3. `pulseaudio --start`
4. `pavucontrol`, go to Configuration tab and choose profile analog stereo output
5. `gnome-alsamixer`  click unmute

I don't know if all these steps are necessary, but just killing pulseaudio and removing the pulse configuration files did not fix this. Without the reboot, alsamixer was already unmuted, yet there was no sound.

Comment: It's work for me! Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS!

Comment: Worked for me as well... did

Comment: ... also run the commands P.Péter suggested, although things didn't work before rebooting, so not sure if those were also necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

Besides purging pulseaudio and pulseaudio-utils and its local lonfigs, I also had to remove all local gstreamer configs. This was on a Dell Latitude E5570.

```
apt purge pulseaudio.*
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/ ~/.local/share/gstreamer-1.0/
apt install pulseaudio
```